# Best strategy to store multiple translation records in DB

Tags: ruby, database, sequel, padrino

Assuming few fields (say under 6/7) whats the best strategy to store multiple language translation for DB records, consider the following two cases.

Say we have a table with the following fields:

`id, title, description`

Every record will have an English and Arabic translation. So, consider the two cases I am using:

Case 1:

Add two more fields: `title_ar` and `description_ar`.

Case 2:

Add a field: `language` and make a composite key out of `id` and `language`.

Considering the complexity of dealing with the composite key (I am using Sequel ORM), I am rethinking whether going with the first approach might be better. Please explain if there are any major drawbacks or advantages for either of the approaches.

Comment: You might want to ask on [dba.se] or [su] for DB schema advice, as Stack Overflow isn't a "Please explain if there are any major drawbacks or advantages for either of the approaches." site. If you were having problems coding a solution then SO would be a better site to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Translator DB Model]

This approach would scale even if it's planned to accommodate multiple language translations.

### Associations

Sentence has many language translations 
Translation belongs to Sentence

---

### Drawbacks of the first approach,

If we were to extend the application to multiple languages then we have to add the corresponding fields to the table

### Advantage of the second approach,

As we have id reference specific to the sentence, we can fetch the corresponding description in desired language quicker.

Comment: Yes, thought about the same. But sadly avoided it as it was emergency and the auto generated admin code would need significant recoding.